# Error message: Exceeded call depth maximum

Tags: smart-contract

I am writing a smart contract and I am receiving this error message:

Error 3070002: Runtime error processing WASM
Error details:
Exceeded call depth maximum

I am confused, since I believe this error is relate to recursion, and I am not using recursion anywhere in my code.

Using print statements, I have found that the error is occuring when emplacing a new table row into a multi-index array:

```
    table.emplace(user, [&](auto & entry)
        {
        entry.setuser(user);
        entry.setvector(myvector); // Error occurs after this line
        });
               // But before this line
```

Comment: What is the definition of `table`?  And what is the type of `myvector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Reason 1

I guess you forgot to set the "table" to be included in the ABI file.

If you are using the old compiler eosiocpp, then add this before your definition of the table struct/class:

```
///@abi table table i64
struct table...
```

If you are using eosio.cdt to compile:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] table...
```

## Reason 2

You forgot to include `EOSLIB_SERIALIZE` in the case where your struct or class uses non-default constructors